# Minimum of the Schatten 1-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Given two operators or non-zero matrices $A$ and $B$, where $A\neq B$, tr$(A)=1$ and tr$(B)=1$ and tr$(A-B)=0$, what is a lower bound of the Schatten p-norm ($p=1$) $\|A-B\|_1$? Any helpful references?

Comment: What type of lower bound do you expect? For $A = B$ (which is possible by your assumptions), you have $\|A-B\|_1 = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to note. $A\neq B$. Also, $A$ and $B$ are nonzero arbitrary matrices. I know that it has a positive lower bound because if tr$C=0$, then tr$|C|> 0$. And since the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, then it means that tr$|C|$ is bounded below by the lowest positive eigenvalue. I'm just at a loss for references.

Answer (score 0):

The lower bound is zero. Consider the matrices
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$
B_\lambda = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 1-\lambda \end{pmatrix}.$$
For $\lambda \ne 1/2$ you have $A \ne B_\lambda$ and $\|A - B_\lambda\|_1=2 \, |1/2 - \lambda|$. For $\lambda \to 1/2$, this converges towards $0$.

Comment: But if $\lambda\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}$, then $A=B$, right? Is there like a perturbation for matrices?

Comment: No. You only have $B_\lambda \to A$, but (as long as $\lambda \ne 1/2$) $B_\lambda \ne A$.